# What's the meaning of "porting" in SIL Open Font License v1.1?

Tags: licensing, license-compatibility, license-notice, font, ofl

It'stated in the license that:

> "Font Software" refers to the set of files released by the Copyright
>   Holder(s) under this license and clearly marked as such. This may
>   include source files, build scripts and documentation.
>
> "Modified Version" refers to any derivative made by adding to, deleting,
>   or substituting -- in part or in whole -- any of the components of the
>   Original Version, by changing formats or by porting the Font Software to a
>   new environment.

i have two questions to ask.

1. what's the meaning of "Font Software", is it include the font that i use in a graphic design software or just the source file like TTF file?
2. I'm designing a vector background which has text in it, If i convert the font(text object) into vector object while designing my artwork, then i export my vector file which include my font that already converted to vector to eps file format and i sell it, is this mean that i change the format and porting the Font Software to a new environment?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of "font software" should be clear from the files themselves in the package you got (they state they are clearly marked). Using the font as part of some document/background is just use of the font, as long as you don't modify it in some way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between a font software and a typeface. A typeface is the design of a font, and a font software is the digital realization of that design, usually in the form of a ttf/otf file. Also note that "Font Software" is a defined term in the OFL license.

As to question two, there may be a difference depending on whether you are distributing a vector or a bitmap format. In particular, the vector format is probably considered a derivative work of the font software, and a bitmap format is probably not. OFL-FAQ 1.1.1 would support the idea that the requirement to distribute the license along side the font does not apply to artwork created using an OFL font.